# Stop words in "All of the words" feature

Tags: lucene

I'm working on "all of these words" feature using Lucene.
I'm using StandardAnalyzer without any stop words.
When user types in words which contain "the", "and" etc, lucene does not return any result.
If i remove the stop words from the input, then lucene gives search results.

Am using booleanquery with BooleanClause.Occur.MUST clause.

Am i missing out on something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you re-index with the same analyzer set up? You have to make the change to the query parser *and* the indexer.